# in excel if content of one cell is same as another than how carry out another function

Tags: excel, if-statement, equations

Excel question. need formula for the following:
If the text content of one cell is the same as the one below then i want to have another cell populated with an equation that adds 2 other columns. is this possible?

Comment: the rest of the question should have been - if 1 cell has the same text content as another i want to be able to have another formula adding 2 otehr cells carried out in another cell

Comment: Mock up some data that shows how your data is and how you want your data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of an IF and INDEX function. It is difficult to provide an exact answer since there is not details of your spreadsheet but here is an example:

```
=IF(A1=A2, INDEX(A1:E6, 1, 5), "Nothing found")
```

This will check if the cells are equal to each other, then take the range A1 to E6 and return the value on the first row and fifth column. If they do not match it will return "Nothing Found".

You can modify this to fit your needs.